# Tutorial on Boolean Logic as used in Assembly

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic

Is there a tutorial somewhere which explains all the intricacies of boolean logic operations which are possible in assembly language. For example, I have no idea what the following assembly code block does:

```
mov     [ebp-8h], 31982853h
mov     eax, [ebp+Ch]
shl     eax, 8
mov     ecx, [ebp+Ch]
shr     ecx, 8
or      eax, ecx
```

I understand what the shl, shr and or instructions do but have no idea about their combined result. 
Can anybody direct me to a tutorial which thoroughly explains boolean logic operations in assembly?

Thanks.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger with a demo value, watch the bits change. Write it out.

Comment: well, the value which is shifted left and right and then or'ed is the argument to a function. It's an int so I can possible try different values but I still think it is better to understand intuitively what the above assembly code does...

Comment: If [ebp+ch] has a 6-bit value on entry, this logic swaps bits 0-2 with bits 3-5 in the final result (eax). It's hard to say what the purpose of that would be. The first instruction is not part of this logic.

Comment: there's nothing boolean in here at all except 'or', and I imagine that you understand what 'or' does.

Comment: It basically says this: `(x << 8) | (x >> 8)`. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotated code:

```
mov     eax, [ebp+Ch]   ; grab our 32-bit value
shl     eax, 8          ; shift it left 8 bits, so the top 8 bits are shifted out 
                        ; and the bottom 8 bits are filled w/ 0
mov     ecx, [ebp+Ch]   ; grab our 32-bit value again
shr     ecx, 8          ; shift this copy right 8 bits, so the bottom 8 bits are 
                        ; shifted out and the top 8 bits are filled w/ 0
or      eax, ecx        ; perform A = A or C for each set of same-aligned bits in
                        ; EAX (A) and ECX (C)
```

So if the original value was ABCD (each letter being an 8-bit byte), then before the or is performed, EAX would have BCD0 and ECX would have 0ABC.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable at `[ebp+Ch]` holds a 16-bit value (i.e. only the 16 least significant bits can be non-zero), then this piece of code efectively swaps its bytes (bits 0 through 7 with bits 8 through 15). However, the result in `eax` after `or eax, ecx` has to be masked (`and`'ed) with 0FFFFh, unless the code that follows uses `ax` instead of `eax`.